# Using Ruby to post an XML request to a webserver

Tags: ruby, http, post, client, net-http

I'm afraid I've not got much experience with posting documents (e.g. XML) over web-servers, so I apologise if my understanding of HTTP is lacking.

I have a basic Mongrel web server set up in a ruby app on `127.0.0.1` port `2000`. (The server).

I am running a separate Ruby app on the same computer. (The client).

I need the client to POST an XML document to the server.

I have tried using Net::HTTP to do this, but I can't find a clear example which tells me what I should do.
I've had a go, but encountered errors. I have broken the request down to make it as basic as possible:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("127.0.0.1", 2000)
http.post('file', 'query=foo') #xc.rb line 6
```

but it results in the following error

```
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Errno::ECONNRESET)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1307:in `send_entity'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1096:in `post'
    from W:/Ruby/A/xc.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I imagine I'm doing it totally wrong. Please can you give me an example (or point me to a tutorial) that should allow me to post some basic data, like `"<tag1>text</tag1>"`. Hopefully, I will then be able to work out setting the appropriate headers and handling the response.

Also, I don't need to use net/http; any free method that doesn't come with extra commercial-use licencing restrictions is fine.

Comment: You're attempting to debug the client. But have you proven that the server functions properly?

Comment: I access the same URL via a web browser and the server correctly does `p` on the request (I've not set it to do anything else yet). When connecting via the client, the server reports that it's receiving a malformed HTTP request `HTTP parse error, malformed request (127.0.0.1): #<Mongrel::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>`. I'm pretty sure that it's just that I don't know how to correctly post the data to the server. If I can find out how I should be doing it, I can debug from there, if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is incredibly easy, when using the [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) gem

```
require 'rest-client'

response = RestClient.post "http://127.0.0.1:2000", "<tag1>text</tag1>", :content_type => "text/xml"
```

Comment: If you check the request server log, the parameters will be `{"tag1"=>"text"}` instead of plain `"<tag1>text</tag1>"`. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know. If you want an answer, you should really ask that as a new question.