# Convert curl command to Ruby http POST(xml) with headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, curl, net-http

How can I make a Http post with a header in Ruby with a xml?

The documentation have something like this curl command and I want to convert it to rails code.

```
$headers = array("Content-type: text/xml", "Content-length: " . strlen($xml),
"Connection: close",);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;if(curl_errno($ch))
print curl_error($ch);else
curl_close($ch);
```

I use Net::HTTP and I'm kinda stuck, I have tried:

```
uri = URI("sample_url")
xml = 'sample xml'
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
req['Content-length'] = xml.length
req['Connection'] = 'close'
req.body = xml

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Go through below link. [Found - Post xml data using ruby.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088752/using-ruby-to-post-an-xml-request-to-a-webserver)

Comment: you can use `httparty` for the same https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
uri = URI("sample_url")
xml = 'sample xml'
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, 'Content-Type' > 'text/xml', 'Content-length' => xml.length,'Connection' => 'close')
req.body = xml

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
```